# Storing information in a file, Python

Tags: python, database, file

I'm making a car rental console base program in Python where I need to save data about cars I store (such as brand, registration number etc).
What would be the ideal type of file for such a thing, and how to iniciate it?

Comment: You can use something like sqlite https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: You can use the `yaml` or `json` module to save the information to these two filetypes. I suggest you using yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite3 to store the information.
You can create a table with columns such as brand,registration number etc.
If the registration number is unique to single type of car you can also take care of that condition in sqlite3
syntax is as simple as:
For creating table:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE COMPANY
        (REGISTRATION_NO INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
        BRAND      TEXT NOT NULL
        );''')
print "Table created successfully";

conn.close()
```

For insertion:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";

conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (REGISTRATION_NO,BRAND) \
     VALUES (1, 'PAGANI')");
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

For more information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html